# For some reason I cant move this bezier curve on the y axis

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

for some reason i just randomly cant move my curve on the y axis when in edit mode. i have tried scaling it and i looked up and down the settings but being new i didn't find anything any help is welcome, i even restarted blender and nothing changed.

if you want to project to look around here it is

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16T1V7JIIwRqPLFrpotQAtB1aeGPboXaJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curve is scaled to zero on the y axis.

[image: scale]

The quickest way to solve that is to *apply scaling* for the object, wich will reset the scaling to `1` – with the curve keeping its shape of course.

To do that, go into *object mode*, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select either *Apply Rotation & Scale* or *Apply Scale*

Comment: Thanks you so much worked great. saved me a lot of time redoing the curve